# Tf Agents Parallel Py Environment With an Environment that has Input Parameters

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-agents

Suppose you have an environment that has input parameters: for example, to create an instance you would use

`env_instance = MyEnv(var_1=3, var_2=5, ...)`

Now suppose you want to create a parallel_py_environment using the environment "MyEnv"? Since you need input parameters, you cannot use

`tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(parallel_py_environment.ParallelPyEnvironment([MyEnv]*int(n_envs)))`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a super class:

```
class MyEnvPar(MyEnv):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(var_1=3, var_2=5)
```

And then you can use

`tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(parallel_py_environment.ParallelPyEnvironment([MyEnvPar]*int(n_envs)))`